# How to make an Editable into a Boolean

Tags: java, android, android-studio, boolean

I'm attempting to make an interactive quiz and I have an *EditText* view that is an *Editable* in my Java code. So long as the user inputs an answer in this field (min. 10 characters), he/she is going to get it correct. However, my code is telling me that I need to set up the *Editable* as a *Boolean* in my *calculateScore* method.

Anyone know how to make the *Editable* as a *Boolean* in my *calculateScore* method while also checking if the minimum character limit is met?

```
package com.example.android.quantummechanicsquiz;

    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        int score = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


        public void radioButtonClicked(View view) {
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.radio_one_correct:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_one_b:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_one_c:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_one_d:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_two_a:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_two_b:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_two_correct:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_two_d:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_four_a:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_four_b:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_four_correct:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_four_d:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_five_a:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_five_b:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_five_c:
                    if (checked) break;

                case R.id.radio_five_correct:
                    if (checked) break;


            }

        }


        private int calculateScore(boolean answerOne, boolean answerTwo, boolean answerThreeA,
                                   boolean answerThreeB, boolean answerThreeC, boolean answerThreeD,
                                   boolean answerFour, boolean answerFive, Editable answerSix) {
            score = 100;

            if (answerOne) {


            } else {

                score = score - 100 / 6;
            }

            if (answerTwo) {


            } else {

                score = score - 100 / 6;
            }

            if (answerThreeA) {

                score = score - 8;

            } else {


            }

            if (answerThreeB) {


            } else {

                score = score + 4;
            }

            if (answerThreeC) {


            } else {

                score = score + 4;
            }

            if (answerThreeD) {

                score = score - 8;

            } else {


            }

            if (answerFour) {


            } else {

                score = score - 100 / 6;
            }

            if (answerFive) {


            } else {

                score = score - 100 / 6;
            }


            if (answerSix) {


            } else {

                score = score - 100 / 6;
            }

            return score;

        }


        public void submitScore(View view) {
            RadioButton answerOne = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_one_correct);
            boolean correctAnswerOne = answerOne.isChecked();

            RadioButton answerTwo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_two_correct);
            boolean correctAnswerTwo = answerTwo.isChecked();

            CheckBox answerThreeA = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_three_a);
            boolean incorrectAnswerThreeA = answerThreeA.isChecked();

            CheckBox answerThreeB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_three_b_correct);
            boolean correctAnswerThreeB = answerThreeB.isChecked();

            CheckBox answerThreeC = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_three_c_correct);
            boolean correctAnswerThreeC = answerThreeC.isChecked();

            CheckBox answerThreeD = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_three_d);
            boolean incorrectAnswerThreeD = answerThreeD.isChecked();

            RadioButton answerFour = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_four_correct);
            boolean correctAnswerFour = answerFour.isChecked();

            RadioButton answerFive = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_five_correct);
            boolean correctAnswerFive = answerFive.isChecked();

            EditText answerSix = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_six_edit_text);
            Editable correctAnswerSix = answerSix.getEditableText();

            int finalScore = calculateScore(correctAnswerOne, correctAnswerTwo,
                    incorrectAnswerThreeA, correctAnswerThreeB, correctAnswerThreeC,
                    incorrectAnswerThreeD, correctAnswerFour, correctAnswerFive, correctAnswerSix);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Congratulations! You have a score of " + finalScore + " out of " +
                    "100", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (answerSix) {
    // something
} else {
    score = score - 100 / 6;
}
```

answerSix is an `Editable` - you're thinking of, say, JS where something undefined === false

You could do something like `if (!answerSix.toString().equals("")) ...` (if I'm understanding what you're looking for correctly)

Comment: Thanks. This worked but what if I wanted answerSix to be scored if it contains greater than a specific amount of characters rather than to check if it contains any?

Comment: `answerSix.toString()` will return the string represented by the editable. String length can be checked by using [`String#length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()), which will return an int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean correctAnswerSix = answerSix.length > 9;
```